# Why bundle loses data type of top-level array?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to pass a 2-dim array of strings into my activity using bundle:

```
bundle.putExtra("myData", serializableArray);
...
data = bundle.getSerializable("myData");
```

So, `data.toString()` returns `[Ljava.lang.Object;@421b93e0`.

In normal java, the string representation of the same deserialized object is `[[Ljava.lang.String;@32d16dc8`.

Why does Bundle pass its data in such a strange way? Can I cast my array into a normal one without casting every `Object` from it to `String[]`?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_tostring_int.htm)

Comment: no, I'm trying to cast Serializable into String[][].